# What to use instead of count with Cursor?

Tags: python, mongodb, collections

I'm pulling data from the database with `find` and checking if anything is there (or if it's empty) by using `count`.
It's yelling at me that `count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead.` but then when i change it, it's saying
 `'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count_documents'`. I tried adding `collection` to `db.find()` but still nothing.

```
def stuff(x):
    return db['stuffs'].find({"stuff": x})

def check_for_stuff(x):
    things = stuff(x)
    if not things.count():
        return None
```

Comment: Post what you're trying to do.

Comment: Post the code that you have used so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count_documents` works at the collection level. So the appropriate way to use it will be to query the DB with `db.collection.count_documents({"stuff": x})` by passing the filter directly to the `count_documents` method.

Hence `check_for_stuff` can be something like:

```
def check_for_stuff(x):
    count = db['stuffs'].estimated_document_count({"stuff": x}) //or db['stuffs'].count_documents({"stuff": x}) or db.collection.count_documents({"stuff": x}) depending on your use case
    ......Do what you need to do....
```

Use [estimated_document_count](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count) for better performance.

[Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1724) is why you need to make two database calls

Comment: But i just want to call the database once >.> to find stuff ... You're saying I then have to call it again to count the same stuff separately?

Comment: It look like that from what I read elsewhere as well (check the edit)